# If a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, can $B$ be written in this way?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix, so we have
$A = P D P^{-1}$.
Suppose $B$ is diagonalizable as well, so $B = QCQ^{-1}$.
It's to my understanding that we can actually write so that $Q = P$.
So $B = PCP^{-1}$.
Why can we write it so that $Q = P$?
I think it has to do with P being a matrix with columns forming an  orthonormal basis, so if $B$ is diagonalizable, it too has a matrix $Q$ with columns forming an orthonormal basis?
Can someone clarify?

Comment: It's not true in general that two matrices are diagonalizable with the same matrix. A diagonalizable matrix need not be diagonalizable with an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: I ask this because I was doing a question that gave a diagonalizable matrix $A$. Then another diagonalizable matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$. I could find $B$ simply by computing $PD^\frac{1}{2}P^{-1}$ where $P$ is found in $A = PD^P^{-1}$.  
I came to my conclusion in OP by letting $B = PCP^{-1}$ so $B^2 = PC^2 P^{-1} = PDP \implies C^2 = D \implies C = D^{1/2}$. Why is my conclusion not valid from the previous equalities?

Comment: It is true that $(PD^{1/2}P^{-1})^2=A$, but it's not necessarily true that $B=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$. For instance, if $A$ has $n$ distinct positive eigenvalues, you have $2n$ choices for a diagonal matrix whose square is $D$.

Comment: When is this true then? I had the question: Solve for $B$ where $B^2 = A$, and the solution says $B = PD^{\frac{1}[2}}P^{-1}.$  
For clarity, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You should ask the question you want an answer to, not a different one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was asking the same question.  
Referring to your comment about the "not necessarily true" part, why is it not necessarily true?  
I thought that if you have a diagonalizable matrices $B,A$ such that $B^n = A = PDP^{-1}$ then $B = PD^{\frac{1}{n}}P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable (this is not true in Michael Burr's answer, but it is assumed in your main question) AND you have that $A = B^2$ (as you write in the comments) THEN, yes there is a matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ and $PBP^{-1}$ are both diagonal. (And it is easy to see that $(PBP^{-1})^2 = PAP^{-1}$ by just expanding the brackets.)

The reason it works in this case is:

**Given that $C$ is diagonalizable, the matrix $PCP^{-1}$ is diagonal if and only if every column of $P$ is an eigenvector of $C$**

So if $PBP^{-1}$ is diagonal for some $P$, all columns of $P$ are eigenvalues of $B$ by the bold statement. It then follows that they are also eigenvectors for $B^2 = A$, as you can see by writing out the definition of eigenvector.

Again by the bold statement (but in the opposite direction), it then follows that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal.

It is easy to see that this also works if $B$ is diagonal and $A = B^n$ for $n = 3, 4$ etc.

In general we do not have that diagonalizable matrices are diagonalizable by the same $P$. If you randomly choose two two by two matrices you have very high probability to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

From the question *in the comments*:

Assume that 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then, we can compute the square as
$$
A=B^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, a diagonalization for $A$ is
$$
A=I\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}I^{-1}
$$
so, the diagonal matrix in this diagonalization is
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, the square root of $D$ is
$$
D^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
But, we don't have the desired equality on $B$:
$$
B\not=ID^{1/2}I^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$